# Can I change the scrollbar color in Safari for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, css, mobile, safari, styling

I'm currently working on a mobile optimized website that has a black background, and it is difficult to see how long a page is while scrolling since the default scrollbar is so dark.

So far I've only been able to find information about changing the scrollbar styles for desktop browsers or iPhone apps.

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863046/setting-the-scrollbar-color-in-safari-for-lion-os-x-10-7) seemed like it could help, but it doesn't seem to be having the same effect on Safari on the iPhone. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, although in your case it certainly could be useful from a ux perspective.

See the [Apple CSS reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html) for more details.

> **Unsupported Properties Specific to Other Browsers**
>
> `scrollbar-3dlight-color`—Microsoft Internet Explorer property.
>
> `scrollbar-arrow-color`—Microsoft Internet Explorer property.
>
> `scrollbar-darkshadow-color`—Microsoft Internet Explorer property.
>
> `scrollbar-face-color`—Microsoft Internet Explorer property.
>
> `scrollbar-highlight-color`—Microsoft Internet Explorer property.
>
> `scrollbar-shadow-color`—Microsoft Internet Explorer property.
>
> `scrollbar-track-color`—Microsoft Internet Explorer property.

You may want to design some kind of gutter into the app so that the scrollbar is visible; otherwise you don't have a lot of options.

Comment: Thank you @egid! I'll suggest the gutter idea to my team, but I think for now we'll probably just leave it as is.

Comment: Glad to help! Depending on what framework you're using, it might be possible to create or emulate a scrollbar that replaces iOS widgets.